# Gecko Browser Click Like Button on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, geckofx

I  am trying to click facebook page like button, but i can't make gecko find the id of attribute.

*Geckofx is working properly.

Here is my Form1.Load:

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/AmaciOlmayanGrup/?fref=ts");
```

And here is documentCompleted Method:

```
        GeckoButtonElement button = new GeckoButtonElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetHtmlElementById("u_jsonp_7_d").DomObject);
        button.Click();
```

What should i do?

Comment: why would you do that anyway? why not just hit the like button with your mouse? likes should always be "real", autoliking and scraping is not allowed on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found Click() doesnt always work on some websites.  Not sure why.  Another way is to get focus on the element then use sendkeys function with ENTER.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.focus(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.100).aspx.